Repeat it tens of thousands of times, It has an error
here after is partial source code of my Application base on Dialog..
void CBitmapCtrl::DrawTrainData(Matrix* Imgs)
{
  if (Imgs->size() > 0 && m_cropWidth != 0 && m_cropHeight != 0)
  {
    struct bitmap_img
    {
      BITMAPINFO bmi;
      unsigned char img[29 * 27 * 3];
    } bitmap_img;
    for (auto n = 0; n < Imgs->size(); n++)
    {
                   // 생성된 이미지 데이터를 RGB각각 복사..
      for (auto i = 0; i < m_cropWidth * m_cropHeight * 3; i += 3)
      {
        bitmap_img.img[i] = static_cast<unsigned char>((*(*Imgs)[n])[i]);
        bitmap_img.img[i + 1] = static_cast<unsigned char>((*(*Imgs)[n])[i + 1]);
        bitmap_img.img[i + 2] = static_cast<unsigned char>((*(*Imgs)[n])[i + 2]);
      }

      BITMAPINFO bmi;
      ZeroMemory(&bmi, sizeof(bmi));
      bmi.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
      bmi.bmiHeader.biWidth = m_cropWidth;
      bmi.bmiHeader.biHeight = -m_cropHeight;
      bmi.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
      bmi.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 24;
      bmi.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
      bitmap_img.bmi = bmi;
      CRect r((n % 10) * m_cropWidth, (n / 10) * m_cropHeight, (n % 10) * m_cropWidth + m_cropWidth, (n / 10) * m_cropHeight + m_cropHeight);

    }
    CBitmap bmp;
    CDC digitDC;
    digitDC.CreateCompatibleDC(&memDC);
    HDC hdc = ::GetDC(this->GetSafeHwnd());
    HBITMAP = hbmp = CreateDIBBitmap(hdc,&(bmi.bmiHeader), CBM_INIT, bitmap_img.img, &bmi,    DIB_RGB_COLORS);
    bmp.m_hObject = hbmp;
    CBitmap* pOldBitmap = digitDC.SelectObject(&bmp);
    memDC.StretchBlt(r.left,r.top,m_cropWidth*3,m_cropHeight*3,&digitDC,0,0,m_cropWidth,     m_cropHeight,SRCCOPY);
    digitDC.SelectObject(pOldBitmap);
    digitDC.DeleteDC();
  }
  Invalidate();
}

Repeat it tens of thousands of times, It has an error.
what is wrong??
check if hdc is null, and then after many times... the hdc = GetDC()  returns NULL.. why?

The code has a resource leak: CBitmap* pOldBitmap = digitDC.SelectObject(&bmp); selects a bitmap into digitDC and never restores the DC before calling digitDC.DeleteDC();. Add digitDC.SelectObject(pOldBitmap); to restore the DC just before deleting it.

I try to digitDC.SelectObject(pOldBitmap); .. but It still return NULL

Firstly, extract a [mcve]. Then, there are tools to display the resources used by a program, which would help you find out which resource it is that you're leaking. In any case, read the docs on the MSDN carefully. I've never encountered a case that puzzled me initially that could not have been solved by more careful study of the docs there.

::GetDC() requires a respective ::ReleaseDC() call after you are done using it (another resource leak). Btw what do you need that DC for? Only for using it as a reference DC for creating the DIB? Don't know, too many DCs... Also storing raster data in the stack is very unusual in image-processing apps (unless you are working with tiny images). Not that this is the source of your problem though.

thanks all, it was cleared... ::ReleaseDC(NULL,hdc) & digitDC.SelectObject(pOldBitmap)  added..

ReleaseDC() should be passed the same HWND as the one used in GetDC(), not NULL. Check the documentation.
